# How can I emit a message to all rooms with flask-socketIO

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

I am having some issues with emiting a message to all rooms witihin my server. I am assigning the users to their rooms by using `joinRoom(data["roomId"])` and I am attempting to broadcast using

```
if not database.checkUserAdmin(data["uid"]):
emit("command",
     {"type": "broadcast",
      "forUser": data["uid"],
      "authorName": "Server",
      "authorId": 0,
      "message": "Test Message.",
      "imageId": [],
      "pingId": [data["uid"]]},
     broadcast=True)
```

Comment: I don't think there's remotely enough of your code here for us to understand what's going on or offer potential solutions.

Comment: @larsks I have a room code structure of 1/1, 1/2, etc. and each room has one of these codes. the mentioned code above get sent when the user sends !broadcast but I need it to emit to all rooms if possible. I have some functions to get these room codes and return them as a list as ["1/1, "1/2"].

Comment: You have to iterate through all your rooms and emit a message to the room accordingly (with room =  ). Further clarification if needed at https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/issues/605